# How can I call OnFailure event of Ajax.BeginForm from server-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

When an error occurred on server side, how can I call OnFailure event of Ajax.BeginForm?
Should I handle the error on OnComplete function?

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function PullIntoTable(e) {
・・・・・
}

function search_start() {
....
}

function Failure() {
        alert("Called!!");
}

.........
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "SearchCompanyJP",
                       new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "search_start", OnSuccess = "PullIntoTable", OnFailure = "Failure", OnComplete = "search_close" }))
{
    <div>
        <span class="label">Company</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName, new { @class = "textbox" })
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="label">Address</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { @class = "textbox" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search"  />
}
```

**XXXService.cs**--which is called by the controller

```
Insertable = false;
if (Insertable)
{
・・・・・
}
else
{
    throw new CustomException(action, message);
}
```

**Global.asax** --- This redirecting does not work beause of ajax. That is why I implemented Failure function.

```
void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.Redirect("/Error", false);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail. What have you tried? Are you saying you have code that's trying to use the OnFailure event and it's not triggering? It would help if you showed your code.

Comment: I did now. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I now commented out Application_Error on Global.asax and then Failure function was called fine. I don't know why...

Comment: It's because you were capturing the error and clearing it in that function. OnFailure only gets called if there's actually an unhandled error.

Comment: oh! Server.ClearError() was the cancer. Thank you!!